# Hermitian metric induced by short exact sequence of sheaves

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Let $L\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle generated by global sections $s_1,...,s_k$. It is well known that there exists a Hermitian metric on $L$ defined in a local trivialization $\psi$ by
$$||\sigma(x)||^2=\dfrac{||\psi(\sigma(x))||^2}{\sum_i||\psi(s_i(x))||^2}.$$
I saw that this can be recovered from the short exact sequence of sheaves
$$0\rightarrow Ker (\varphi) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X^k \xrightarrow{\varphi} \mathcal{O}(L)\rightarrow 0,$$
where $\varphi$ is defined by
$$\varphi(f_1,...,f_k)=\sum_if_is_i.$$
Can someone explain to me how to get it from that sequence?

Comment: You saw where? That short exact sequence merely rephrases the statement that $L$ is globally generated.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes but apparently there is a way to use the surjection in order define a metric from the obvious one on $\mathcal{O}_X^k$